# How to use a dict comprehension to split a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a dict in the form:

```
data = {"var1":"600103", "var2":[{"a":"1","b":"2"}]}
```

I would like the output to be:

```
op = {"var1":"600103","var2[0]":{"a":"1","b":"2"}}
```

I am currently using loops to manually loop through.  I'd like to know if there's a more pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind mutating this key? In general, how will you apply this mutation? Also, where's the list? What are you splitting?

Comment: A person working on the server screwed up the whole API that we are currently using.  I'm trying to patch things up while we fix the db.  The var2 field will have more entries.  so data could also be data = {"var1":"600103", "var2":[{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"22","b":"555}]} in which case we'll need "var[1]" in the key list.

Comment: Nothing more pythonic than a nested loop I'm afraid.

Comment: man i was afraid of that :|

Comment: It's true you'll need the nested loop, but that can be made a _bit_ more pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't what you're already doing, you can eliminate the need for a nested loop by using a dict comprehension for the values which are lists.

```
data = {"var1":"600103", "var2":[{"a":"1","b":"2"}, {"a":"22","b":"555"}]}

op = {}
for k in data:
    if not isinstance(data[k], list): 
        op[k] = data[k]
    else:
        op.update({k + '[{}]'.format(i) : data[k][i] for i in range(len(data[k])) })
```

And, your output will look like this:

```
{'var1': '600103', 'var2[1]': {'a': '22', 'b': '555'}, 'var2[0]': {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}}
```

Comment: Yup, no worries. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is very pythonic or not but I know for sure that it is difficult to read :S
Sorry, just playing... ;)

```
data = {"var1":"600103", "var2":[{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"3","b":"4"},{"a":"5","b":"6"},{"a":"7","b":"8"}], "var3":"600103"}
reduce(
    lambda a, b: dict(a.items() + b.items()),
    [
        dict(map(lambda (idx, i): ('{0}[{1}]'.format(key, idx), i), enumerate(value))) if type(value) is list else {key: value} 
        for key, value 
        in data.items()
    ]
)
```

output:

```
{'var1': '600103',
 'var2[0]': {'a': '1', 'b': '2'},
 'var2[1]': {'a': '3', 'b': '4'},
 'var2[2]': {'a': '5', 'b': '6'},
 'var2[3]': {'a': '7', 'b': '8'},
 'var3': '600103'}
```